# Media Query not working for iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, css, cordova, media-queries, cordova-2.0.0

**@media** query is not working in case of **iPhone 5 and iPad 4 OS**. I have used following **CSS** for styling each OS and device for different screen.

I explicitly checked that my iPad and iPhone width and height and based on that only i have kept the media queries. This works **fine** on ANDROID OS.

```
/*@media print {*/
/* iPhone 5 (Portrait) */
@media screen and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation: portrait) {
     #map_canvas {
        border: 1px dashed #C0C0C0; 
        width: 290px;
        height: 473px;
      }
}

/* iPad 4 (Portrait) */
@media screen and (max-device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
 #map_canvas {
    border: 1px dashed #C0C0C0; 
    width: 735px;
    height: 929px;
  }
}

/* iPad 4 (Landscape) */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  #map_canvas {
    border: 1px dashed #C0C0C0;
    width: 990px;
    height: 673px;
  }
}

/* Samsung 10.1 inch (Portrait) */
@media screen and (max-device-height: 1280px) and (orientation: portrait) {
 #map_canvas {
    border: 1px dashed #C0C0C0; 
    width: 790px;
    height: 1140px;
  }
}

/* Samsung 10.1 inch (Landscape) */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1280px) and (orientation: landscape) {
 #map_canvas {
    border: 1px dashed #C0C0C0; 
    width: 1230px;
    height: 680px;
  }
}

/* Samsung 7.0 inch (Portrait) */
@media screen and (max-device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
 #map_canvas {
    border: 1px dashed #C0C0C0; 
    width: 570px;
    height: 875px;
  }
}

/* Samsung 7.0 inch (Landscape) */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  #map_canvas {
    border: 1px dashed #C0C0C0;
    width: 990px;
    height: 455px;
  }
}

@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
  html, body {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Each time i tested with various changes in above code, I am getting the LAST CSS being referred for applying the style.

I found one link, (which i have not yet tried but going to try soon as mac is available) but have question about that too ([iphone/ipad media query issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910777/iphone-ipad-media-query-issues)). Can anyone explain the reason behind that Is pixel ratio matters in this case??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excerpted from https://mislav.net/2010/04/targeted-css/

> You should be aware that orientation media query, although supported on the iPad, doesn’t work on the iPhone (tested with v3.1.3). Fortunately, size queries like width and device-width work, so layout-switching is possible without JavaScript with some combination of those.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because the new Apple devices have a higher pixel ratio density.  You should put this meta tag in the head of your document and your media queries will work everywhere:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

By the way, the higher pixel ratio for the new apple products is called "retina display."

If you do have access the iPhone, ipad, etc... try viewing this website:

http://mattstow.com/viewport-size.html

on those devices to **see the viewport size** of the device.  Then, **add the meta tag**, and you will see that the **viewport size changes**.

Comment: Okey, so does this mean that `viewport` is the actual area used by our application?? Above code says that i am setting my width of my app to device width?? right?? Does it has to do something with iOS devices??

Comment: Yes. It has to do with all devices.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah my site is rendering in 1104px width on iPhone i added meta tag and minimum and maximum device width in css here is the [link of my site](https://www.kalvie.com) . If possible please help me out i'm not able to post question on stack overflow due to some restrictions.

Comment: Please create a "mock" site on, for example, jsFiddle with only the mimimum code that reproduces the problem and post a new question.  That's what I would so at least.