# Safari on iOS doesn't work with media queries

Tags: ios, css, html, safari, windows-10

My problem is that I cannot get media query to work on `iPhone 5s iOS 9.3.2 Safari`. I have a full screen video on my page what I'd like to change into an image on mobile. I have followed [this tutorial](http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video) to make it happen.

I have specified the `viewport` like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

I have included `!important` tag in every css entry I need to be changed when being 640px, like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px) {

 html {
  background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed !important;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
 }
 #video {
  display: none !important; 
 }
 body{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important; 
  /*also tried with background:transparent !important*/
 }
}
```

I decided to use `640px` as it is the exact amount of pixels what gets rendered on iPhone 5s according to [this source](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions).

I have specified that the `background` should be `transparent` as it seems to be the only option to work around the default template style. Meaning when background becomes transparent the background image shows up.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301910/iphone-is-ignoring-css-media-queries-viewport-tag-present-working-in-desktop) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818277/media-query-not-working-for-iphone-and-ipad). I have applied the suggested solutions to my problem but none of them worked.

**NOTE: I don't have the Mac machine to test this issue via iPhone's web inspector. Making a VM on Windows seems to be not a one hour job.**

I have tested my code in `Chrome 50.0.2661.102 m (64-bit)`, `Mozilla 46.0.1` and `Edge on Windows Phone` everything works fine.

I have tried to work with `Safari 5.1.7` (the last version released for Windows), but it seems to be very outdated (as expected).

I have also cleared the cache with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and tried to use Incognito mode.

**UPDATE:** if I specify the color (for the sake of testing) before the image I will be then able to see the specified color in Safari, but no image:

```
background: green url('image.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed !important;
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: i think you forgot close bracket  }

Comment: @JentiDabhi fixed the question. But this is not the issue with current config.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for help I've found a workaround just for my case. Thanks to @daemeron's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37553385/5153030).

So instead of implementing separate styleheets for different devices it is just possible to hide the annoying `Play` button on the background by:

```
*::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
 display: none!important;
 -webkit-appearance: none
}
```

This works great on iPhone and Windows 10 mobile. Exactly what I was looking for.